# YTD growth as a dashlet

Tags: extension, drupal-views, dashlet, custom-reports

I want to display a dashlet showing growth percentage YTD this year, comparing with the same period last year.

I used the extension [Advanced Fundraising reports](https://civicrm.org/extensions/advanced-fundraising-reports/102) to achieve this, but that extension gave me performance issues related to other site-specific features.

Now I am looking into Drupal Views, in the combination with this extension [Drupal Views as CiviCRM dashlets](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_views_dashlets).

However, I am struggling with how to use Drupal Views to calculate percentage growth of YTD CiviCRM contributions amount.

How to show the difference between YTD total contribution amount, and the same period last year as percentage, in a CiviCRM Dashlet?

Comment: Do you use Views PHP?  If you do, and if you're somewhat familiar with PHP, you may be able to use PHP to calculate that in a view.

Comment: I am not familiar to PHP, so any tip is much appreciated

Comment: There's also the Views Calc module (I'm afraid I don't know whether it'll produce what you're looking for, but it should handle the calculations)

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on dashboard caching with a long duration it might mitigate the performance issues enough for you to use the Advanced Fundraising reports?

Comment: It will probably not, the issue is not so much in the dashboard caching unfortunately

Comment: @ErikH you are perfectly right, it is more complex than just a caching issue